# downloading pip for an offline instalation

Tags: python, pip, offline

I have one computer connected to the internet and another that is stand alone (Mint). I used freeze to create the requirements file and then tried to use

pip install --download /somefolder -r requirements.txt

however, this is failing for reasons unknown to me. Specifically :

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PAM==0.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (from versions: 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1)

Honestly, I don't know what PAM is or how I could have gotten a future version. I think I did all my installations via pip)

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Well, is PAM listed in the requirements.txt file? The error is saying PAM v0.4.2 does not exist but it is listed in the requirements.txt file.

Comment: Also is there a typo in your pip call? You call `requirements.txt` but the error code specifies `requirement.txt`.

Comment: The real file name I used contained the name of my computer, the typo in name is only in the post. And yes, PAM is in the file, line 6